# How to make sharepoint 2010 site as readonly

Tags: permissions, site

How to make sharepoint 2010 site as readonly.

Note:

It should not be applicable for custom administrator group,Except the administrator group other group will get the site as readonly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should specify if "by site" you mean actually a sub-site as in SPWeb or a site collection, as in SPSite. If a Site Collection, simply Lock-it by setting it to Read Only, which shall be valid across the whole site Collection (no edits though, for Site Collection Admin neither).

If you are more in the 2nd situation, where a business need requires it, then indeed a custom permission Level (where you strip off required permissions) would give you flexibility and it must be defined at the Site Collection level. If you need to add more dynamic, use SharePoint Designer Workflow to assign these permissions to users (no-code required). Otherwise, go for code, where options multiply exponentially, depending on your exact needs.

Comment: Instructions for setting the entire site collection to read only here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20106/all-sites-are-read-only-even-for-site-administrators/20110#20110

Answer (score 7):

I would assign the site's Visitor group a read-only permission level throughout the site.

Comment: u mean to say that i need to assign the read only property to all groups except admin.

Comment: Correct. You could make a Visitors group, grant them read only, and then have Site Owners and Site Collection Admin. who can control the rest.

Comment: This is probably the simplest and best solution. However, it obviously won't work where you have broken permissions.

Answer (score 4):

The OOB way to do this is to lock the site through Central Administration > Site Collections > Configure Quotas and Locks > Site Lock Information

Here you can either

- **Not locked** to unlock the site collection and make it available to
  users.
- **Adding content prevented** to prevent users from adding new content to
  the site collection. Updates and deletions are still allowed.
- **Read-only** (blocks additions, updates, and deletions) to prevent users
  from adding, updating, or deleting content.
- **No access** to prevent users from accessing the site collection and its
  content. Users who attempt to access the site receive an error.

This is the way SharePoint itself locks access when it takes backups.
More information on locking [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263238.aspx).

If this is too restrictive, consider creating a **Deny Write** policy on your web application. This will overwrite whatever permissions that have been given to the specified users in the site collection. Read more on policies [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608071.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

To make a site read only go to Central Admin->Configure quotas and locks->Specify the site->Select Read-Only radio button.