# How to decommission a SharePoint site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, site-collection

We have a SharePoint server 2010. We have migrated the content to SharePoint online. Now we have to plan a decommission of a SharePoint site collection.

What best practices for decommissioning a SharePoint site collection on SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like the old site to be available but read only, consider making the [site read only via the Central Administration](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/22019/91738).

If you would like to completely decommission the site, then I would recommend the following:

- Take multiple SQL server backups of the content database
- Check the backups integrity by doing a test restore
- Store the backups in a safe storage location
- Decommission the servers

Answer (score 1):

The decommissioning process is mainly related to the whole server, not a specific site, However, if you would like to stop accessing to site collection, you have to do the following:

1. Lock access to the current site collection using the below PowerShell Script

   ```
   Set-SPSite -Identity http://SiteCollectionURL/ -LockState NoAccess
   ```

> Read more at [Prevent access to site collection SharePoint 2016](https://debug.to/2664/prevent-access-to-site-collection-sharepoint-2016)

---

If you would like to delete the site collection, you have to do the following:

2. Take a backup from the SharePoint site.

> Read more at [Back and restore a site collection](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/move-site-collection-to-another-web-application/)
> 3. Take a backup for the content database that holds the site collection.
> 4. Perform a Test backup by restoring the site from the backup to ensure that rollback.
> 5. Remove the site to the recycle bin using PowerShell.

```
   Remove-SPSite -Identity 'https://sitename' -GradualDelete -Confirm:$False
```

> Read more at [Remove-SPSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/remove-spsite?view=sharepoint-server-ps)